# show that {S1,S2}has an infimum.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

did i show this right ?

$A \neq \emptyset , $

Pt(A)= the   set   of all partitions of A

Let $\preceq$ be an partial ordering on Pt(A) 
so that

(Pt(A),$\preceq$) is a partially ordered set.

now 
$\forall S_1 , S_2 \in Pt(A) $ $S_1 \preceq S_2 \Leftrightarrow $   $\forall C\in S_1 $
$ \exists D\in S_2$ |$C\subseteq D$

show that {$S_1,S_2$}has an infimum

now $S\in ${ $S_1 , S_2$ }

let $X\in Pt(A) | X \preceq S$,
$\forall S\in${ $S_1 , S_2$ }

so
X is a lower bound of { $S_1 , S_2$ }

now let  X'={$X|X \preceq S$,
$\forall S\in$ {$S_1 , S_2$ } }

if I$\in$X' | $\forall X\in X', X\preceq I $ then

the infi({$S_1 , S_2$ })=I

so {$S_1 , S_2$ } has an Infimum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few problems with your argument. First, how do you know that $X$ exists? It does, but you can’t simply assume this: if you want to use the fact, you have to prove it. But the biggest problem comes at the end, when you write:

> if I$\in$X' | $\forall X\in X', X\preceq I $ then
>
> the infi({$S_1 , S_2$ })=I
>
> so {$S_1 , S_2$ } has an Infimum

Look again at what you’ve said: **if** there is some element $I$ of $X'$ with a certain property, then $\{S_1,S_2\}$ has an infimum. But what if no such $I$ exists? You are in fact showing that if $\{S_1,S_2\}$ has an infimum, then $\{S_1,S_2\}$ has an infimum, which is true but doesn’t help you that that $\{S_1,S_2\}$ actually **does** have an infimum.

The way to prove that $\{S_1,S_2\}$ has an infimum for every $S_1,S_2\in\operatorname{Pt}(A)$ is actually to construct the partition that is the infimum. You want a partition $S$ of $A$ with two properties:

1. $S\preceq S_1$ and $S\preceq S_2$, and
2. if $T\in\operatorname{Pt}(A)$, and $T\preceq S_1$ and $T\preceq S_2$, then $T\preceq S$.

In order to get (1), you need to ensure that for each $C\in S$ there are $D_1\in S_1$ and $D_2\in S_2$ such that $C\subseteq D_1$ and $C\subseteq D_2$. In other words, there must be $D_1\in S_1$ and $D_2\in S_2$ such that $C\subseteq D_1\cap D_2$. An easy way to ensure this would be to make sure that every $C\in S$ **is** of the form $D_1\cap D_2$ for some $D_1\in S_1$ and $D_2\in S_2$. This would also make every $C\in S$ as large as it could possibly be, which seems like a good way to try to make (2) hold as well.

So let $$S=\Big\{D_1\cap D_2:D_1\in S_1,D_2\in S_2,\text{ and }D_1\cap D_2\ne\varnothing\Big\}\;.$$

Now see if you can show that $S$ is a partition of $A$ that satisfies (1) and (2). If you get stuck, I’ll give you more help, but you ought to see how far you can get from here on your own first.

Answer (score 0):

You have proven that if such an $I$ exists, then there is an infimum. But you have not shown that such an $I$ exists.

Your proof doesn't use any properties of partitions; you're working in a specific poset, so you should need to use these properties.